# if my class is not public than XML Encoder and Decoder doesn`t work

Tags: xml-serialization

Xml is work only class is public.what i do if class is not public?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about .NET XML serialization with [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) then this type can serialize only public classes. You could use [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

For Java, `java.beans.XMLDecoder` also only unmarshalls public classes. There is no way to overwrite this behavior and to provide custom object handlers.

There are other libraries, such as **XStream**, which have various options to encode/decode other types of classes, control the marshalling process or use factory classes to create instances of private classes which were otherwise not accessible.